# Как при помощи API "В контакте" получить данные своего аккаунта?

Tags: android, api

Есть андроид-приложение с авторизацией через "В контакте". Успешно заходит. 
Нужно после авторизации из своего аккаунта "ВК" получить String name, String foto, String email.

В google api есть методы :

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
String name = user.getDisplayName();
String uid = user.getUid();
String email = user.getEmail();
```

Нужны аналогичные методы для "В контакте"

Answer (score 0):

https://vk.com/dev/users.get -   метод, который возвращает расширенную информацию о пользователе(ях). Если не указывать `id`, то запрос на текущего пользователя...Необходимые возвращаемые поля задаются в нем через `FIELDS`

Простой запрос:

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get();
```

[Официальная документация, подпункт 4.1.1](https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk?f=4.%20%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%20API)

Загрузка произвольного метода API:

```
VKRequest request = new VKRequest("users.get", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_id, verified, sex, bdate, city, country"));
```

[Официальная документация, подпункт 5](https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk?f=4.1.%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)

---

В целом может быть примерно так:

```
//  VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name, last_name"));
VKRequest request = new VKRequest("users.get");
request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        super.onComplete(response);
        //код обработки объекта
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(VKError error) {
        super.onError(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Я так понял в request грузятся данные аккаунта. А вот как из request их достать? google api есть методы :                                               
            name = user.getDisplayName();
            uid = user.getUid();
            email = user.getEmail(); а в контакте путаница какая то

Comment: @RuslanChepizhko https://vk.com/dev/users.get - это и есть метод, который возвращает расширенную информацию о пользователе(ях). Если не указывать `id`, то запрос на текущего пользователя...Необходимые возвращаемые поля задаются в нем через `FIELDS`.......

Comment: Как мне из этого запроса получить String name, String email и String foto? Это нужно для записи в бд.

Comment: @RuslanChepizhko ответ приходит в response

Comment: com.vk.sdk.api.VKResponse@3cf0d60  -  вот response! Где тут имя или фото?

Comment: @RuslanChepizhko очевидно в `response[0].first_name` например. Так как вы не понимаете как работать с SDK и языком - то советую почитать литературу по нему, прежде чем начать писать что-то

Comment: Я не пойму, зачем установив  API VK в приложение, и авторизовавшись на своём устройстве, мне делать опять запрос в сеть получать ответ парсить и т.д?! У меня же все мои данные уже на устройстве! Неужели их никак нельзя получить?

Comment: Авторизовавшись аккаунтом google я спокойно получаю свои данныеFirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
String name = user.getDisplayName();
String uid = user.getUid();
String email = user.getEmail();

Comment: " Так как вы не понимаете как работать с SDK и языком - то советую почитать литературу по нему, прежде чем начать писать что-то"- вы я вижу не пишете для android, и даёте мне ответы из WEB.

Comment: @RuslanChepizhko в ответе отсутствуют советы из WEB. А свой хрустальный шар можете выкинуть на свалку - вы что-то не то "видите"

Comment: вы мне даёте не те советы, я вас отвечать не заставляю

Comment: @RuslanChepizhko вы некорректно сформулировали изначально вопрос ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: возможно не совсем корректно

Answer (score 0):

Пройтись по массиву:

```
        VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get();

        request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                super.onComplete(response);
                VKList<VKApiUserFull> vkApiUserFulls = (VKList<VKApiUserFull>) response.parsedModel;

             //здесь
                for (VKApiUserFull vkApiUserFull : vkApiUserFulls){
                   System.out.println(vkApiUserFull.first_name);
                }

            }
        });
```